# LinkedIn r_basicprofile and r_fullprofile scope fields and why are both "redundant"?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am new to using the LinkedIn API. I would like to have my site members provide OAuth 2.0 authentication to access their profiles but there is a small point of confusion I have regarding permission scope.

In the OAuth User Agreement you can check which default scope you want your app to have so you don't have to pass the scope as a query parameter. But there it says: "Selecting both r_basicprofile and r_fullprofile is redundant."

But in the documentation, the fields for r_basicprofile and r_fullprofile are all distinct. It doesn't specifically say that if the scope is r_fullprofile it also includes r_basicprofile.

One might guess it does. It seems that would be logical. But I wanted to confirm. Or perhaps I can't use the default scope settings and need to specify both as a query parameter when making the call to generate the authentication code?

In my case I would like to be able to access, for example, a user's "specialties" (listed in r_basicprofile) as well as their "skills" (listed in r_fullprofile).

The documentation says that for the basic profile fields "These fields require the r_basicprofile member permission" and similarly for the full profile fields it says "These fields require the r_fullprofile member permission". So I feel like I ought to include both in the scope.

So why does it say selecting both is "redundant"?

Thanks,

doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r_fullprofile` is a superset of `r_basicprofile` so you only need one of both and you can access "specialties" with both but "skills" only with `r_fullprofile`

Comment: That makes logical sense. I wanted to be sure because of the wording in the documentation. I'll make sure the scope just specifies r_fullprofile in this case then. Thanks for your reply.